# Github public site with Jekyll does not update anymore

Tags: html, github, jekyll, liquid

Excuse me again for seeking help for my site at [meredithhu.github.io](http://meredithhu.github.io).

All the codes are here: https://github.com/meredithhu/meredithhu.github.io.

As you can see the updated codes never get updated any more, for instance, 
the About page here [https://github.com/meredithhu/meredithhu.github.io/About](http://meredithhu.github.io/About)
never gets updated according to my most recent changes in codes:
https://github.com/meredithhu/meredithhu.github.io/blob/master/About/index.html

The same goes for my Reseach/Misc/Memo pages...

Could anyone give me some hints how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the error you should address: `Liquid Exception: Invalid Date: 'nil' is not a valid datetime. in /_layouts/blog.html`.

You should use `{{ page.date | date_to_string }}` only if `page.date` is a valid date, so you can check if it is not `nil` updating `_layouts/blog.html`:

```
{%if page.date%}
 <p class="meta">{{ page.date | date_to_string }}</p>
{%endif%}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've updated both the _layouts/blog.html and _layouts/post.html: https://github.com/meredithhu/meredithhu.github.io/blob/master/_layouts/post.html

Comment: still the same bug...would you mind letting me know what I did wrong...? Thanks so much :D

Comment: Completely remove this line: `<!--<p class="meta">{{ page.date | date_to_string }}</p>-->`, these are html comment but jekyll tries to process it anyway.

Comment: Hi @marcanuy, you are indirectly/not answering the question and I hope you are aware of that :-) Next time the OP (or anyone else googling it) has the same problem (website not being updated), your answer will be irrelevant

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert OP's website doesn't update anymore because it has an error (as you already pointed out) , you found the commit that introduced the bug, but didn't provide a solution as OP wanted: "Could anyone give me some hints how to fix the problem?". Pointing out the commit that introduced the bug has no value for all those that will google "website not being updated" without pointing out how to fix at least this particular case, title is a bit vague.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad for being ambiguous about the problem... Thanks so much to you both! WIll ask another separate question about it.